# OCaml - Typerror with right construction

Tags: ocaml, typeerror

```
type ide = string;;
type integer = int;;

(*Eccezioni*)
exception WrongMatchException;;
exception EmptyEnvException;;
exception TypeErrorException;;
exception UnboundRecordException;;
exception OutOfBoundException;;

type exp =
    | Ide of ide (*Identificatore*)
    | Int of int (*Valori Interi*)
    | Bool of bool (*Valori Booleani, true=1, false=0*)
    | Add of exp * exp (*Operatori Matematici*)
    | Sub of exp * exp
    | Mul of exp * exp
    | Eq of exp * exp
    | Leq of exp * exp
    | And of exp * exp (*Operatori Logici*)
    | Or of exp * exp
    | Not of exp
    | Function of ide * ide * exp (*Funzione con un parametro, non ricorsiva*)
    | IfThenElse of exp * exp * exp (*Classico If Then Else *)
    | LetIn of ide * exp * exp (*Blocco Let*)
    | FunApply of ide * exp (*Applicazione funzionale Ide(E)*)
    | Tupla of ide * elts (*Espressione Tupla*)
    | GetIndex of elts * exp (*Accesso Elemento Tupla*)
    | GetFirstN of elts * exp (* Seleziona elementi Tupla*)
    | TupleEquals of elts * elts (*Confronto tra tuple*)
    | Map of ide * exp (*Applica funzione ad elementi tupla*)
    | ListaE of elts
and
(*Elementi di una tupla*)
    elts = Elemento of exp | Lista of exp list
;;

    (* the empty environment *)
    (* emptyEnv: 'a -> 'b *)
let emptyEnv = fun x -> raise EmptyEnvException;;
let emptyFunEnv = fun x -> raise EmptyEnvException;;
let emptyTuplaEnv = fun x -> raise EmptyEnvException;;
    (*bind: ('a -> 'b) -> ide -> exp -> (ide -> exp ) *)
let bind env (variable: ide) value = fun y ->
            if variable = y then value else env y;;

    (*Funzioni di supporto*)
(*Casting da exp a tipi primitivi*)
let asint = function Int x -> x | _ -> failwith "not an integer";;
let asbool = function Bool x -> x | _ -> failwith "not a boolean";;
let aslist = function Lista x -> x | _ -> failwith "not a list";;
(*Cast da Lista_exp to Lista_elts *)
let aslist_e = function ListaE x -> x | _ -> failwith "not a list_e";;
let tupla2Lista = function Tupla(x, y) -> y | _ -> failwith "non a tupla";;

let rec getElement lista index = match lista with
    | [] -> raise OutOfBoundException
    | primo::elems -> if index = 0 then primo else getElement elems (index-1);;

let rec first lista number = if number = 0 then [] else
    let lista1 = aslist(lista) in
        match lista1 with
        | [] -> raise OutOfBoundException
        | primo::elems -> let resto = Lista(elems) in primo::(first resto (number-1));;

let rec map lista funct = match lista with
    | [] -> []
    | elem::elems -> (funct elem)::(map elems funct);;

let rec valTuple lista eval_fun env funenv tenv = match lista with
    | [] -> []
    | elem::elems -> (eval_fun elem env funenv tenv)::(valTuple elems eval_fun env funenv tenv);;

let funDeclr (expression: exp) env funenv = match expression with
    | Function (funName, param, body) -> bind funenv funName (param, body, env)
    | _ -> raise WrongMatchException;;

let tupleDeclr (tupla: exp) env tenv = match tupla with
    | Tupla (id, lista) -> bind tenv id lista
    | _ -> raise WrongMatchException;;

let append elemento lista2 = let lista21 = aslist (aslist_e lista2)
                                in elemento::lista21

let appendE elemExp elemExpLE = let listaE = aslist_e elemExpLE in
                                match listaE with
                                | Elemento (expr) -> Lista(elemExp::[expr])
                                | Lista (exprlist) -> Lista(elemExp::exprlist);;

let rec eval (expression: exp) env funenv tenv =
    match expression with
    | Int i -> Int(i)
    | Ide i -> env i
    | Bool i -> Bool(i)
    | Add (e1, e2) -> Int(asint(eval e1 env funenv tenv) + asint(eval e2 env funenv tenv))
    | Sub (e1, e2) -> Int(asint(eval e1 env funenv tenv) - asint(eval e2 env funenv tenv))
    | Mul (e1, e2) -> Int(asint(eval e1 env funenv tenv) * asint(eval e2 env funenv tenv))
    | Eq (e1, e2) -> if (eval e1 env funenv tenv) = (eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Leq (e1, e2) -> if (eval e1 env funenv tenv) <= (eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | And (e1, e2) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) && asbool(eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Or (e1, e2) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) || asbool(eval e2 env funenv tenv) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Not (e1) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) then Bool(false) else Bool(true)
    | FunApply (funName, arg) -> (*Chiamata di funzione*)
        let value = eval arg env funenv tenv in
                let (param, body, ambiente) = funenv funName in
                        let env1 = bind env param value in
                            eval body env1 funenv tenv
    | IfThenElse (e1, e2, e3) -> if asbool(eval e1 env funenv tenv) then eval e2 env funenv tenv
                                                                else eval e3 env funenv tenv
    | LetIn (id, value, body) -> let value = eval value env funenv tenv in
                                    let env1 = bind env id value in
                                        eval body env1 funenv tenv
    (*| Tupla (id, lista) -> let lista1 = aslist(lista) in
                            let lista0 = valTuple lista1 eval env funenv tenv in
                                    ListaE(Lista(lista0))*)
    | GetIndex (id, i) -> let index = asint(eval i env funenv tenv) in
                            let lista = aslist(id) in
                                getElement lista index
    | GetFirstN (exp, i) -> let index = asint(eval i env funenv tenv) in
                                ListaE(Lista(first exp index))
    | TupleEquals (exp1, exp2) -> if aslist(exp1) = aslist(exp2) then Bool(true) else Bool(false)
    | Map (funx, exp) -> let lista = aslist(aslist_e(eval exp env funenv tenv)) in
                         let (param, body, ambiente) = funenv funx in
                        (match lista with
                          | [] -> ListaE(Lista([]))
                          | x::xs ->
                            let value = eval x env funenv tenv in
                                let env1 = bind env param value in
                                    let remaining = ListaE(Lista(xs)) in
                                        ListaE(appendE (eval body env1 funenv tenv)
                                                (eval (Map (funx,remaining)) env1 funenv tenv))
                        )
    | ListaE(exp) ->  let lista = aslist(aslist_e(exp)) in 
                        (match lista with
                            | [] -> ListaE (Lista [])
                            | x::xs -> let value = eval x env funenv tenv in
                                        let remaining = ListaE(Lista(xs)) in
                                            let coda = (eval remaining env funenv tenv) in  
                                                let risultato = appendE value coda in
                                                    ListaE( risultato )
                        )
    | Tupla(x,y) -> ListaE(y)
    | _ -> raise WrongMatchException
;;
```

Given the code, trying to compile its, compiler says there is error with type evaluation at ListaE(exp) in eval function (without ListaE(exp) in match code compile without problems). Error shown is  `Error: This expression has type elts but an expression was expected of type exp`
Any ideas where is the problem? Type matching is right, eval is exp, so lets are rights. ListaE is constructor of exp type so by definition is right and appendE return exp type. I don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `aslist_e` expects to see a `ListaE xxx` value. But you're passing the `xxx` value itself (the value inside the `ListaE` constructor).

It might work to say:

```
let lista = aslist exp in
```